# For-loop in lua with löve2D, deleting variable

Tags: for-loop, lua, love2d

i'm a bit beginner about coding, and my english isn't great, i hope i'll be able to make my question clear:

So I have a `for`-loop in my code, and 2 `if` in it, in each `if`, I see if something is true or false, if it's true, I delete a portion of the loop. like that:

```
for n=#Test,1, -1 do

   if Test[n].delete == true then 
      table.remove(Test, n )
   end

  if Test[n].y > 0 then
      table.remove(Test, n )
  end

end
```

kind of like that, and my problem is, if the first `if` make `Test[n]` being deleted, then the game crash at the next `if` because `Test[n]` Doesn't exist anymore. I solved the problem by making 2 `for`-loop, one for each `if`.

But I saw someone who did it without 2 `for`-loop, and it's not crashing, I tried to figure what was wrong but I can't find it.

If someone could find what is wrong with what I wrote, I would be thankful!

So here is the moment that makes problem in my code, on line 9, if the condition are met, i `table.remove(ListeTirs, n )`, then on line 17, when code try to find it again for test it, it bug :

```
for n=#ListeTirs,1, -1 do
  if ListeTirs[n].Type == "Gentils" 
  then local nAliens
    for nAliens=#ListeAliens,1,-1 do
      if
      Collide(ListeTirs[n], ListeAliens[nAliens]) == true
      then
      ListeTirs[n].Supprime = true
      table.remove(ListeTirs, n ) 
      ListeAliens[nAliens].Supprime = true
      table.remove(ListeAliens, nAliens)
      end
    end
  end  

  if
    ListeTirs[n].y < 0 - ListeTirs[n].HauteurMoitie or ListeTirs[n].y > Hauteur + ListeTirs[n].HauteurMoitie or ListeTirs[n].x > Largeur + ListeTirs[n].LargeurMoitie or ListeTirs[n].x < 0 - ListeTirs[n].LargeurMoitie
    then

    ListeTirs[n].Supprime = true
    table.remove(ListeTirs, n)


  end 

end
```

I hope it's clear, I could post the whole code but I don't feel it's necessary, if it is, I will add it.

Thank you :)

Comment: An alternative to Egor's method would be to use an `elseif` statement. The problem with your example is that two items can be removed in one loop, which would cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
for n=#Test,1, -1 do
   local should_be_removed

   -- just mark for deletion
   if Test[n].delete = true then 
      should_be_removed = true
   end

   -- just mark for deletion
   if Test[n].y > 0 then
      should_be_removed = true
   end

   -- actually delete (at the very end of the loop body)
   if should_be_removed then
      table.remove(Test, n )
   end
end
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, pretty clear answer, thank you much :)